# Flatlist inside tab navigator is scrolling to top on state change in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, flatlist

[Here you can see the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeTEE.gif)

Here is my whole Navigator functional component. I'm trying to implement two tabs using Tab Navigator. One to display the cryptos and the other to display the forex data.

The problem is, when I try to load more data on reaching the flatlist's end, the flatlist is scrolling to the top since I'm making a state change [page+1].

```
const Navigator = () => {    
  const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

  const renderItems = ({ item }) => (
    <Text>{item.name}<Text>
  );  

  const fetchMarketData = async () => {
    console.log("Fetching");
    const marketData = await getCryptoMarketData({ page });
    if (marketData != "Network Error") {
      const ids = data.map((item) => item.id);
      let newData = marketData.filter((item) => !ids.includes(item.id));
      setData([...data, ...newData]);
      setFetching(false);
    } else {
      setFetching(false);
      Alert.alert(marketData, "Sorry for the inconvenience");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setFetching(true);
    const data = async () => {
      await fetchMarketData();
    };
  }, [page]);

  const handleLoadMore = async () => {
    setFetching(true);
    setPage((page) => page + 1);
  };

  const ScreenA = () => (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={renderItems}
      scrollEventThrottle={16}
      onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0}
    />
  );  

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => screenOptions(route)}
      keyboardDismissMode="auto"
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Crypto" component={ScreenA} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Forex" component={ScreenC} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default Navigator;
```

OnEndReached is firing the handleLoadMore function and after the state change on data, the Flatlist is scrolling to the top.

Comment: you should have "fetchMarketData" func inside  SreenA component where Flatlist exists to avoid child rerenders by parent => i think this is issue here, or post whole ScreenA code if its in same FC ( functional component )

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can I add hooks inside, I want to fetch data as soon as the screen loads so I'm using use Effect. Even though, I tried your approach but it's re-rendering multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st reason**

- you have typo in "fetchMarketData", how exactly u get "newData" because i cant see it anywhere, maybe it should be "marketData" if not then u adding SAME old data PLUS undefined`[...data, ...undefined]`

**2nd reason**

reason why is that u call `setPage(page + 1)` and then "fetchMarketData" this is bad why ? because **setState** is async and it can be changed instant or after 5 secound, so u dont know when its changed and this is why we have hooks, you can use "useEffect" to handle this

change your "handleLoadMore" for example like this

```js
const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setPage(page + 1);
  };
```

add useEffect hook that runs when "page" state changes

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
 (async() => {
    setFetching(true)
    const marketData = await getCryptoMarketData({ page });
    if (marketData != "Network Error") {
      setData([...data, ...marketData]);
    } else {
      Alert.alert(marketData, "Sorry for the inconvenience");
    }
    setFetching(false)
})()
}, [page])
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful.

**Reason 1** =>
`const ids = data.map((item) => item.id);
let newData = marketData.filter((item) => !ids.includes(item.id));`

I actually used newData to filter out previously added data.

**Reason 2** =>
The flatlist is scrolling to top as soon as I set page to 1 in handleLoadMore. So, even though I use hook based on page change, it is scrolling to the top.

Comment: can u then update your example with whole code ?

Comment: @Engzan I've updated bro. Please take a look and I want the solution so badly. it'll be a great help if you do so. 

Comment: @Lahfir navigator should contains only Navigation stuff to avoid rerenders, add everything else to separate file or same file but not inside "Navigator", so basicly "Navigator" should contains in this case only "return" code with "Tab.Navigator" and "Tab.Screen"

Comment: Thank you so much @Engzan. That worked